# C++ | Are random constrained arrays considered resources?

Tags: c++, random, copy-constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, assignment-operator

I am taking a class on C++. In our text is says:

> Memory that an object allocates at run-time represents a resource of that object's class.

If an array has a random length, is it considered a resource and thus require a copy constructor/assignment operator?

```
class someclass{


    public :
        int length;
        int* randomarray;

};

int main(){

    someclass obj;

    obj.length = rand() % 50 + 1;

    obj.randomarray = new int[obj.length];

    return 0;

}
```

Edit>> 
This is a *terminology* question.

Comment: What do you mean by "random values"?

Comment: Randomly generated numbers. Will edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "random constrained arrays"? Are you talking about arrays with randomly-determined length?

Comment: What do you mean by a  "random constrained array": does the adjective "random" apply to the word "constrained", or "array" or to the (unsaid) "contents".

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Orthogonal query. Randomly generated numbers are in no way coupled to dynamic memory allocation. Your question is completely unclear and pepperd with a serious misconception  probably.

Comment: You'll have to be way more specific, perhaps provide a code sample. If you're talking about the result of something like `rand()`, this doesn't fit the description since this is an r-value and there are no permanent resources allocated in the process.

Comment: see edit with code snippet

Comment: The text creates a strong link between dynamic members and user input. My question is: since 'random' and 'user input' are both unknowable, are they not equivalent in terms of 'dynamic' and thus /both/ resources?

Comment: It's a terminology question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the word 'resource' has a specific meaning, in relation to the idiom "resource acquisition is initialization", which I assume is what you are learning about and what the question is really asking.

In simple terms, a resource is something that, after you acquire it, you have to clean it up / release it. Meaning, put it back where you found it, return it to the system, etc., and typically because, someone else (some other program) might want to use it soon. It could be a piece of hardware, like a device, maybe a printer. It could be, a software construct, like a lock used in threading. Or it could be simply memory.

When you get random bits from a function like `rand`, you don't need to give them back to anyone or anything, and no one else is going to use them after you are done with them. You can just forget about them afterwards. So they should not be considered a resource for purposes of this idiom, or the rule of three, etc. If the random bits are passed around via heap-allocated memory, then that is a resource that might need to be freed. But I would say in that case that the random bits are not the resource, only the memory that contains them is.

Comment: So then in the case of the random size array in my example, would the array be considered a resource? It is allocated dynamically.

Comment: Comment repost --->The text creates a strong link between dynamic members and user input. My question is: since 'random' and 'user input' are both unknowable, are they not equivalent in terms of 'dynamic' and thus /both/ resources?

Comment: Yes, so in my take of it, neither random bits nor user input are a "resource". Typically, user input has a variable size, and has to be held in dynamic memory. But then that memory is the resource, not the user input itself. To make it concrete -- suppose I'm making a struct that I use to hold command line arguments to my program. The struct might have a bunch of members of type `std::string`. The struct itself is not a resource, and does not need a dtor, even though it represents user input. But each string is a resource, and its implementation satisfies the rule of three.

Answer (score 3):

> Memory that an object **allocates** at run-time represents a resource of that object's class.

The key word is "to allocate". Random values are *generated* at runtime, but it's up to you how you store them (perhaps allocating memory, perhaps not).

#### Generation doesn't imply Allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all memory used whether allocated dynamically or statically is a resource.  For your example above, you need to deallocate the memory allocated for your array.  And as for the copy constructor and assignment operator yes, unless you want the default behavior of those which would NOT handle the dynamic memory in the array, assuming it had been allocated before use of the copy constructor or assignment operator because you don't allocate it in a constructor.